# Workbench installed but not working ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql-workbench

I've upgrade ubuntu 14.0.4 to 16.04 but after instalation mysql-workbench is not available. When tring to install again I've some dependecies problem so I've used --force to install it.

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.5-1ubu1404-amd64.deb
```

Workbench installed but not opening ...

Comment: Using `sudo apt install mysql-workbench` with Ubuntu16, perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem with folowing:

- Download workbench new version.
- Install workbench

  **sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.7-1ubu1604-amd64.deb**
- Now install dependencies

  **sudo apt-get -f install**

Its works for me.

Comment: No need of `dpkg`  or download.